# Rq Worker with multiple connections

Tags: python, redis, distributed-computing

I have 3 servers in the same network. On each of those servers a redis service and some sort of producer are running. The producer enqueues jobs to a local rq queue named `tasks`.
So each server has it's own `tasks` queue.

Also, there's one more server that is running an rq worker. Is it possible to have that worker check the `tasks` queue on each of the 3 servers?

I have tried creating a list of connections

```
import redis
from rq import Queue, Worker
from rq import push_connection
# urls = [url1, url2, url3]
connections = list(map(redis.from_url, urls))
```

which I then use to create a list of queues.

```
queues = list(map(lambda c: Queue('tasks', connection=c), connections))
```

Afterwards I push all the connections

```
for connection in connections:
    push_connection(connection)
```

and pass the queues to `Worker`

```
Worker(queues=queues).work()
```

This results in the worker only listening on `tasks` on whatever connection was pushed last.

I've been looking into the code on [rq](https://github.com/rq/rq) and I think I could write a custom worker class that does this but before I do that I wanted to ask if there's another way. Maybe even another queueing framework entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay , I solved the problem. I'm still unsure whether I have permission to post actual source code here so I will outline my solution.

I had to override `register_birth(self)`, `register_death(self)`, and `dequeue_job_and_maintain_ttl(self, timeout)`. The original implementation for these functions can be found [here](https://github.com/rq/rq/blob/master/rq/worker.py).

#### `register_birth(self) -> None`

Basically, you have to iterate over all connections, `push_connection(connection)`, complete the registration process, and `pop_connection()`.

Be careful to only list the queues corresponding to that connection in the `mapping` variable. The original implementation uses `queue_names(self)` to get a list of queue names. You'll have to do the same thing `queue_names(self)` does but only for the relevant queues.

#### `register_death(self) -> None`

Essentially the same as `register_birth`. Iterate over all connections, `push_connection(connection)`, complete the same steps as the original implementation, and `pop_connection()`.

#### `dequeue_job_and_maintain_ttl(self, timeout: Optional[int]) -> Tuple[Job, Queue]`

Let's take a look at the [original implementation of this function](https://github.com/rq/rq/blob/master/rq/worker.py#L970). We'll want to keep everything the same until we get to the `try` block. Here we want to iterate over all connections *endlessly*. You can do this by using [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

Inside the loop `push_connection(connection)`, and set `self.connection` to the current connection. If `self.connection = connection` is missing, the result of the job may not be properly returned.

Now we'll proceed to call `self.queue_class.dequeue_any` similar to the original implementation. But we'll set the timeout to `1` so we can proceed to check another connection if the current one doesn't have any jobs for the worker.

Make sure `self.queue_class.dequeue_any` is called with a list of queues corresponding to the current connection. In this case `queues` contains only the relevant queues.

```
result = self.queue_class.dequeue_any(
    queues, 1, connection=connection, job_class=self.job_class)
```

Afterwards `pop_connection()`, and do the same check on `result` as the original implementation. If `result` is not `None` we've found a job to do and need to `break` out of the loop.

Keep everything else from the original implementation. Don't forget the `break` at the end of the `try` block. It breaks out of the `while True` loop.

#### Another thing

Queues contain a reference to their connection. You could use this to create a list of `(connection, queues)` where `queues` contains all queues with connection `connection`.

If you pass the resulting list to [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) you get the endless iterator you need in overriding `dequeue_job_and_maintain_ttl`.

Update (2023-12-12)

#### `heartbeat(timeout: Optional[int] = None, pipeline: Optional[Pipeline] = None) -> None`

Recently, I had to fix what turned out to be a heartbeat related issue and had to override `heartbeat`. If the given `pipeline` parameter is not None then just call the parent implementation. Otherwise, call the parent implementation for all connections in `self.connections = {q.connection for q in self.queues}`.

#### `maintain_heartbeats(job: Job)`

This function is called while the worker is waiting for the horse to finish the task. It only handles one connection, so we'll extend its functionality to handle multiple connections. Again, we iterate over all connections and implement almost the same behaviour as the parent. In the parent implementation of `maintain_heartbeats` the result of executing the operations added to the pipeline is expected to have at least 3 elements. This is not the case when the connection we're checking is not the same connection as the given job. Thus, before accessing the array we have to check whether the connection we are currently looking at is the same as the job's connection. The `Job` class has a `connection` attribute.

#### `set_state(self, state: str, pipeline: Optional[Pipeline] = None)`

Call the parent implementation for each connection. This should ensure that the state of the worker is correct on every connection.